# Signing Mac app presents dialog that it "can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer"

Tags: macos, signing

I have signed my .app file:

[image]

Only the .app is signed and looks like this inside:

[image]

But when I: Compress to .zip -> Upload -> Download -> Unpack -> Open

I still get this message:

[image]

Any idea what I might have missed in my signing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application has been signed using a Mac App Store development certificate. Gatekeeper's default settings require that the application be signed using a [Developer ID](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/) certificate.

Comment: The current certificate is of type "Mac Development". You mean that I would need one of the type "Developer ID Application"? If so: It seems like I only can create the first but not second kind. How come?

Comment: Right, you need a "Developer ID Application" certificate. As far as I know the only requirements to create one are a paid Mac developer program membership and that you are the team agent / admin for the account.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Guess I just need to leave it to the admin then =)